# Assign a pointer to point to a struct

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I'm trying to make an array of structs made according to user's input.
first of all - I initialise an array using calloc:

```
  BusLine* head = calloc (num_of_lines, sizeof (BusLine));
```

Then in a loop I try to create structs according to input (read bus is the function that makes the structs):

```
BusLine* create_list(BusLine* head, size_t num){
  for (int i = 0; i<num; i++){
    BusLine bus = read_bus();
    *(head+i) = bus;
  }
  return head;
}
```

But when I try to do that I always end up with a SIGSEGV. According the best of my knowledge - it is possible to pass a variable to a calloced pointer, so I am struggeling with understanding the problem here.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: There is nothing in particular wrong with your code, but the problem could be related to what is actually stored inside the "BusLine" class. You really need to learn to use a debugger, since it eliminates a lot of confusion for beginners.

Comment: This seems okay to me. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: How are `num_of_lines` and `num` related? Are they the same? Same question applies to `head` variable and `head` parameter.

Comment: Although `*(head+i)` is not wrong, it is completely equivalent to `head[i]`, which is the clearer, more conventional spelling.

Comment: It is not wrong to use the intermediate `bus` variable, but neither do I see how it serves any useful purpose.  I would just write `head[i] = read_bus();`.

Comment: What is BusLine ? A struct or a pointer ?